# When JavaScriptSerializer is mandatory?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

here i attach a sample code. they used JavaScriptSerializer  to generate data in json format and send back the data to client

GetPersons() has been called by jquery ajax function. code here

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Default.aspx/GetPersons",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: "{}",
     dataType: "json",
     success: AjaxSucceeded,
     error: AjaxFailed
 }); 

[WebMethod()]
public static string GetPersons()
{
    List<person> persons = new List<person>()
    {
        new Person { UId = 1, Name = "Brij", Address = "Noida"},
        new Person { UId = 2, Name = "Rahul", Address = "New Delhi" },
        new Person { UId = 3, Name = "John0", Address = "Chris"}
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return ser.Serialize(persons);
}
```

when a method is decorated by WebMethod then data is generated in json format automatically when they are return. if you guys look it closely 
then u can see GetPersons() string instead of List. why some one return string instead of List . if they would return List 
then data need not to be generated manually in json format. am i right?

so i just need to know why people use JavaScriptSerializer to generate data in json format. so please tell me what kind of situation one has to use

JavaScriptSerializer  to generate data manually in json format?

please discuss in detail.......thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON serialization is not mandatory. You could return a list of comma-separated value pairs. The difference in that the list would have to be parsed on the client to turn it back into an array or data object. The beauty of JSON is it is ALREADY a native JavaScript object.

This becomes more important when data structures become more complex.

Comment: it would be more helpful if u give me two small sample code one return list and one return like ser.Serialize(persons);
as a result i can understand what u tried to say....u said list would have to be parsed on the client to turn it back into an array and JSON is it is ALREADY a native JavaScript object.